# How does pool size actually work with Spring's scheduled tasks?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I have a task scheduled as such:

```
<task:scheduler id="notification.scheduler" pool-size="15" />

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="notification.scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="notificationProcessor" method="sendNextQueueEvent" fixed-rate="500" />
    <task:scheduled ref="notificationProcessor" method="deleteNextCompletedEvent" fixed-rate="60000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

I think I have a misunderstanding of how the scheduled tasks work with the pool size. Despite the pool-size being 15, it seems only one thread is being used. For example, if I have fifteen events in the queue, I would think there would be fifteen threads checking every minute to remove an event from the queue. Obviously, this is wrong.

How can I make it so that there's fifteen threads calling this method for the time interval using Spring's scheduler abstraction?

Edit: What I want to accomplish is this: Every half second, I want to check to see if there are queued events to send. When this is done, I want to send a maximum of 15 (if 15 exist). How would I accomplish this using the spring abstractions for the java thread stuff?

Answer (score 6):

First of all `<task:scheduler/>` is a wrapper around `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` extending `ThreadPoolExecutor`. JavaDoc for the latter says:

> even core threads are initially created and started only when new tasks arrive

Secondly you must understand that scheduled tasks (this is a Java feature, not Spring's) do not run concurrently, even if they take longer time than repeat interval. They simply wait. So you don't have 15 events waiting in the queue, you have 15 executions that are late and wait for that single thread. No need to create another one because next execution has to wait for the previous one to finish. Again, this is how Java scheduling framework works.

Of course if you have several different tasks scheduled, more threads will be created.

Comment: Thank you. I think I mostly understand the relation between things now. So (and probably not the most elegant solution), if I wanted 15 different threads processing queue events, I'd have to repeat '<task:scheduled ref="notificationProcessor" method="sendNextQueueEvent" fixed-rate="500" />' 15 times?

Comment: So, I guess, what is the value of pool-size? Is it that if there are five tasks but the pool-size is two, the other tasks will have to wait until the first two are done?

Comment: @AHungerArtist: no, actually a better approach would be to have a Spring-managed pool with `pool-size="15"` simply adding a new job to an ordinary `ExecutorService` with 15 threads. Then it will process the events using all threads as fast as possible. Please explain your requiremenets better, you want to run some code every 500ms in 15 threads concurrently? Either add it to this question or open another one so we can think of some elegant solution. Remember to post follow-up link if any.

Comment: I will edit this question to more fully explain my desired results. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Updated to explain what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AHungerArtist: basically my advice is still valid. Check your queue (I guess you have some external queue with events) every 500 ms using spring (1 thread is enough). Take as much as possible from the queue (but not more than 15) and forward these events one after another to a separate thread pool (see: `Executors` class in JDK) with 15 threads. This makes me wonder - why don't you simply put your events directly in a pool with 15 threads (you don't need Spring for that) and avoid 500ms latency?

Answer (score 4):

Spring's [`task:scheduler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/scheduling.html#threadPoolTaskExecutor) is by default a bean properties wrapper for [`java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> corePoolSize - the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they
>   are idle.

This does not guarantee that the `pools-size` property is equivalent to having that number of *active* threads. On the other hand, you should note that at *any given point in time* there can be only a maximum number of threads equal to processing cores on the machine that you're using; i.e. all other threads will be waiting to switch to `RUNNING` mode and continue execution.

Also, in Spring's documentation, it mentions that if this is not what you need, you can also take advantage of `ConcurrentTaskExecutor`.

Comment: If I have four cores, shouldn't there be at least four threads? I only see one. If I have a hundred events in my queue, when this scheduler starts, shouldn't I immediately see four calls of sendNextQueueEvent, one from each thread?

Comment: Four is the maximum number of _concurrent active_ threads you can have; it's not the initial default setup. Seeing the calls is also dependent on different things such as the concurrency model of the queue you use for the events and the rate/period with which the task is executed. I hope this helps.